# Under what conditions on its entries is A invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Under what conditions on its entries is A invertible?
$$ 
A = \left [ \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & 0 \\ f & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the fact that $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det(A)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Switch the first and the third rows: you get a lower triangular matrix which is invertible if and only if the entries on the diagonal are non zero.

Switching two rows is an elementary operation that preserves and reflects invertibility.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{A}$ is invertible if and only if it is non singular, that is when $\det(\mathbf{A})\ne0$

$\det(\mathbf{A}) =-ecf$

So $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible if and only if $e$, $c$ and $f$ are non-zero.